# Inserir intervalo de números numa tabela automáticamente SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

A questão é a seguinte quero inserir num campo de uma tabela um intervalo de números que vai de 100 a 1 000 000 000 e não queria estar a fazer 1 a 1. Como posso fazer isso de forma automática?

Em SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já achei um resposta é a seguinte:

```
DECLARE @num INT = 100
WHILE(@num<200)
begin
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[tableName]([row1],[row2],[row3],[row4])
VALUES (@num,value2,value3,value4)
SET @num = @num + 1
end
```